# selenium dragAndDrop not dragging and dropping, though selector seems OK

Tags: firefox, selenium, drag-and-drop, draggable, selenium-ide

I'm trying to use dragAndDrop in the Firefox selenium IDE but it's not working.

I'm a big fan of selenium but this problem has been driving me crazy for the last day.

I have a dragAndDrop test:

```
dragAndDrop
//div[contains(text(),"Lori F.")]/../../
0,160
```

but it doesn't do the drag and drop.  I have seen it work a couple of times but not sure why / why not now.  Seems to sometimes work and sometimes not.

The selector itself DOES works when I click on the IDE [find] button.  It highlights the `DIV` I am trying to move.  So this is not the 'usual' problem I have in selenium of not actually being able to select the object with the right xpath.

The HTML it is going against is:

```
<div class="fc-event-inner fc-event-skin" style="background-color: yellow;">
  <div class="fc-event-head fc-event-skin"></div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="fc-event-title">
      Lori F., Marshal H., Chris W., Kenna T.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fc-event-bg"></div>
</div>
```

When that actual step tries to run, the browser does actually 'flash' the object, indicating that it's able to select it via the path OK, but the drag and drop doesn't happen.

I have tried dragAndDropToObject, using a div, but this didn't work because the DIV itself needs an x,y coordinate in order to 'land' on the right spot.

Two problems I have found [this may help other people] - and eliminated - were that 1) zooming in/out on the screen messed up the x,y coordinate for the drop, so I stopped doing that and 2) Using the element inspector in firefox seemed to also stop it working.  So I believe I've eliminated both of these as potential causes.

Being able to test drag-and-drop is pretty important as many applications are now taking various ajax routes with this kinda stuff so being able to test it is key!

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes drag and drop does not work properly (I don't know why).

So you may use workaround to simulate the same actions but in another way:

1) mouseDownAt(locator, coordString) - here you press down left mouse button and hold it

2) sometimes it is useful to wait for reaction (e.g. wait for tooltip appears or something else). At least put small pause to be sure that mouse "captured" the object and can drag it (tests could run very fast and browser may not react properly)

3) mouseMoveAt(locator, coordString) - drag where you need

4) mouseUpAt(locator, coordString) - release your mouse button finishing drag and drop

Also, you may add in the beginning of these steps setMouseSpeed(pixels) to make the mouse move slowly (to be sure it can drag) and in the end setMouseSpeed back to its default value (default is 10 meaning that mouse step is 10 pexels. Setting speed 3-5 pixels will make the mouse move slower).

Try to experiment with: mouse speed by setting different values and wait (after mouseDownAt) by changing locators (tooltip, shadow if there is any) or just put a pause of 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Yummy, sounds like fun, thanks!  I'm in the middle of another project right now but I will try this as soon as I get time as I need it to work.